# ESXi 5.5 Windows Server 2008 Std VM - Unable to ping other hosts on same subnet

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, ping

I am in the position of trying to set up a server system for my company using some provided instructions.  I am not an IT professional, but am the only option available at the moment. So, I apologise in advance for my lack of knowledge - I'm very much trying to learn as I go. Anyway...

I have installed and configured ESXi 5.5 to run on a pair of host servers.  After configuring the network and storage, my first task is to create a VM for Active Directory and DNS Server roles.

I have set up a VM and installed Windows Server 2008 Std (and updated VMware Tools). After entering the IPv4 details to the Network Adapters, I attempted to ping the IP addresses of other hosts on the subnet. All responses return host is unreachable.  No roles or features have been added or configured at this point.   I am able to ping the VM's own IP addresses.

Trying to ping the VM from another host on the subnet results in the same outcome - host unreachable.

I have disable the Windows firewalls and confirmed their status using *netsh*, just in case they were causing a problem - no effect.

I have disabled IPv6 at the Network Adapters.

Incidentally, I have installed other VMs on to the server to test (Win 7, Win Server 2012), using the same network settings as for the problem VM, I have no issues getting them to communicate with other hosts. Unfortunately, Win Server 2012 isn't compatible with elements of the version of VMware I have, so I have to find a way of getting Win Server 2008 up and running.

I'd be very grateful for any advice at this point.

Comment: Let's see your vswitch config first please - also it's not best practice to run DNS services inside a virtual environment that relies on DNS - it's a circular-dependency

Comment: Is there anything specific you're looking for wrt the vswitch?  Noted, re the DNS server.

Comment: like a picture of its layout

Comment: I think the first place to look to solve your problem is the virtual switches and the upstream network configuration.  I'll assume you are using standard vSwitches.  when you go and look a the the vSwitch config, do you have a "green plug" next to the physical nic?  This indicates if the physical connection is there.  Next question, is the upstream physical network switch that connects to your ESX server presenting an access port or a trunk port (802.1X vlan)?  What is the VLAN ID you have set in your port groups?

Comment: A screenshot of the vSwitch config is quite important to get this fixed. Also, what network adapter are you running on the 2012 servers that aren't communicating?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the correct VLAN (Virtual Machine Settings --> Network Adapter --> Network Connection (Make Sure to use the correct Network).

Can you ping any other servers on the same network?
Can you ping your gateway from the client?

Try this:
Remove your current NIC from VM. (Take note of the IP if is using a Static IP, you will need to assign the ip again).

Open CMD and type: ***devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1***
then type ***devmgmt.msc***

On the Device Manager window, go to View --> Show Hidden Devices
on Network adapters, remove everything hidden (ghost items)

Add a new NIC to your computer (Make sure to assign the correct VLAN)

Assign the IP (Windows).

Try to ping any server again. Post the results.